# What is Surge Rating?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I recently found a Relic slot item that says "Use: Increases Critical Rating and Surge Rating by 50 for 20 seconds."

Critical Rating deals with Critical Hits, but what is Surge Rating?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What effect do the lesser character stats have?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45065/what-effect-do-the-lesser-character-stats-have)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both of them are related to critical hits. Critical Rating affects how often do you make them, Surge Rating affects how much damage do they deal if you make them.

For details, hover over Critical Chance and Critical Multiplier on your character sheet:

[image: Screenshots of Critical Chance and Critical Multiplier popups]

Comment: Note that for e.g. a Bounty Hunter, Aim instead of Willpower will be used to calculate the critical chance.