# What effect do the lesser character stats have?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

There are 3 major character stats (Mastery, Presence, and Endurance) plus Expertise for PvP. On your character sheet, you can mouse over the stat and it gives you a decent summary of what the stat does. (More melee damage, increase effectiveness of your companion, etc.)

But there are 9 other stats that you find on various armor stats or abilities. But there aren't all listed directly as a stat on the character page.

For example, Accuracy is, but only if you switch to the correct drop-option and you're a class that can use it. If the below stats aren't listed in any of the drop-downs on your character page, does that mean that can't help your class at all and should be ignored completely?

What do the following stats do for your character?

- Accuracy
- Alacrity
- Armor
- Critical
- Damage Reduction
- Defense
- Power
- Shield
- Surge

Comment: Just clarifying the bounty; there was a question that was posted where the user was interested in fact-checking for the answer currently here. If it's possible to show verification for all of the stats or justify your knowledge of their meaning then I'll reward the bounty.

Answer (score 19):

The exact effects of these stats vary with level and sometimes with class, so precise effects aren't possible in the general case like this.

All definitions are from the <kbd>C</kbd>aracter page in-game.

> **Absorption** - more absorption means more damage mitigated when you shield an attack.
>
> **Accuracy** - reduces chance to "miss" your opponent. Once you have 0% chance to miss, reduces opponents defenses instead.
>
> **Alacrity** - makes spells channel, tick, or cast faster.
>
> **Armor** - Reduces kinetic and energy damage by a constant %.
>
> **Critical** - increases chance for a critical strike.
>
> **Surge** - increases the bonus % on a critical strike.
>
> **Damage Reduction** - Just a listing of the various types of damage on your character, currently
>
> **Defense** - increases parry and deflect rates
>
> **Power** - provides a bonus to tech and force abilities. (Your abilities scale with Power. Your class' main stat provides Power as one of its benefits. Depending on class, this could be Aim, Strength, Cunning, or Willpower)
>
> **Shield** - base chance to shield.
>
> **Glance Rating** - increases chance to shield

Comment: Defense increases parry and deflect rates. Shield increases your *chance* for an attack to be successfully shielded (think block chance.) Damage Reduction simply shows exactly what it sounds like. It isn't a 'stat' per se, but rather *the result* of stats like Armor, as well as any buffs you might have running. You're also missing Expertise, which increases damage done, and decreases damage taken, but *only in PVP*.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I didn't include Expertise because the OP already mentioned it.

Comment: Do you have a source on these ?

Comment: @Robotsushi - ingame, from the character menus. Some are buried within uther stats (like Surge's definition hiding under the Critical stat)

Comment: "Stats" do not change with class — not the calculations to come up with stats anyway. How much each bonus gear affects the final calculation is, however, based on a lot of factors, including the ability used. And different classes have different abilities; so the statement "The exact values of these stats change with ... class" is not really technically correct, but it's sort of the same idea in the end.

Comment: @Mufasa Eh? Strength gives Sith Warriors Force Power. It does not give Sith Inquisitors Force Power (Willpower does instead). In addition, the amount of rating required to equal 1% effect changes with level (lower levels require fewer rating points). I'll change "values" to "effects". Does that clear it up?

Comment: @RavenDreamer Yes

Answer (score 2):

[According to an administrator of swtorgeeks.com](http://www.swtorgeeks.com/showthread.php/19-Swtor-Primary-amp-Secondary-Stats):

> - Accuracy – Hit Rating and armor and spell penetration
> - Alacrity – Haste
> - Armor – reduces physical and kinetic damage (all Tech and Force powers unless listed otherwise are Kinetic)
> - Crit – gives melee, force and tech crit
> - Defense – increases Parry/Deflect
> - Power – adds melee, force and tech damage
> - Shield – increases chance to be shielded on attack
> - Surge – increased critical damage

And some you didn't mention:

> - Absorption – increases the % of damage shaved off shielded attacks
> - Expertise – PvP stat. (Similar to Resilience in Wow) Increase damage and healing and reduces damage tanken
> - Force/Tech Power – Works exactly like power
> - Presence – boost companion health, damage and healing

These are also the same effects described in [The Star Wars Leveling Guide](http://www.starwarsmmolevelingguide.com/character-stats/).

Comment: There is no "Force / Tech Power" stat. Hilts / barrels give Force / Tech Power respectively, *but* this is found nowhere else. The stat you can actually find on gear is simply **power**.

Comment: It sounds to me like it *is* a stat, it's just unused... Why else would Hilts/barrels give it then?

Comment: @John because it's functionally identical. No force user is even able *to equip* any item with Tech Power and vice versa. As with a number of other things, it's just an odd UI holdover from beta.

Comment: My point is that the distinction is arbitrary. If you're a Jedi/ Sith, you use Force Power, and all Power on your Gear becomes Force Power. If you're one of the other classes, you use Tech Power, and all Power on your Gear becomes Tech Power. It'd be more meaningful if Jedi could pick up a blaster, but because they can't, it's essentially meaningless.

Comment: @John: If power is used on a tech-based weapon, it is called Tech Power, if power is used on a Force-based weapon, it is called Force Power. Either way, it does what Power does (adds to damage), but it does it for the corresponding stat for that weapon. There isn't a "Melee Power" which would make more sense with this system. So it is a little confusing that it is differentiated in some places, but not others.

Comment: @Raven I see. So should I remove that or does it really not matter?

Comment: @John I'd just change the description to "works exactly like power" and be done with it.

Comment: FYI, I didn't list Presence because it is a core stat that is listed with tooltips next to your other main stats. And it is a pretty simple calculation: Health bonus: 5 x Presence, Damange bonus: Presence / 5, Healing bonus: 0.14 * Presence. Okay, that last one isn't real easy. But at least it's simple math.

Comment: @Mufasa `0.14 * Presence` is close to `Presence / 7`. I don't know which one is used by the game, but for a quick calculation the latter might be easier.