# Power vs. Force Power

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

For a sith inquisitor focusing on PvP healing, what stat should I focus on and why? Power or Force Power?

Both seem to push my force abilities, but what's the better choice when faced with a decision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between the two. They are functionally the same.

Power is a stat that is seen across all classes, but the definition of "Force Power" is usually only see on gear that is worn by Force users (Sith Warrior, Sith Inquisitor Jedi Knight, Jedi Consular), same goes for "Tech Power" for Tech users (Imperial Agent/Bounty Hunter/Smuggler/Storm Trooper).

The answer can be found in this other related question: [What effect do the lesser character stats have?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45065/what-effect-do-the-lesser-character-stats-have)

Comment: So, what you're saying is when I have two items and they provide differnet amounts of force/power I should always go with the highest of them, regardless if it's _normal_ power or _force_ power?

Comment: You should also look at other stats of the item as well, such as expertise, stamina, and willpower (which also provides a little bit of power).

Comment: Of course - The example was under the assumption that all other stats are the same on both items.

Comment: I think the system has been overhauled to remove the power/techpower/forcepower distinctions, rendering this answer obsolete.