# Attack Vs Triage Adrenals; (Force Power + Debuff vs Raw Power)

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

[image] [image]

When looking at questions like [Power vs. Force Power](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47763/power-vs-force-power) and [What effect do the lesser character stats have?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45065/what-effect-do-the-lesser-character-stats-have), everyone seems to indicate that Power and Force Power have the exact same effect. If that's true, why does one have a 50% damage dealt reduction, and one does not?  Doesn't that make the Triage Adrenal terrible?

Comment: Hmm, mind control...

Answer (score 4):

There's no functional difference. It's a leftover from a beta mechanic that worked differently, or a dev mistake or who knows, but the takeaway is that there's no good reason to use the Triage Adrenal *at this point in time*.

The rebuff indicates that there *may* be done developer intent to make the triage adrenal stronger for healers, but it's not borne out in current mechanics. Alternately? The developer intent may be to someday delete the triage adrenal entirely.

Comment: Surely the name "Triage" suggests the person using it will be healing, so, the 50% reduction is only applied to attack force. As the Power increase will affect healing as well as offensive abilites this seems like the logical reason for the Adrenal.

Comment: @Tib right. The question of developer intent is one of whether the Triage adrenal was planned to be better for healers and then scrapped, or whether it was planned to be better for healers and is bugged. Either way, the fact is that *at this time* there's no good reason to use the Triage Adrenal.

Comment: Sorry, yes. I was working on the assumption that the healer could utilise both the force and tech power increase, which is obviously not the case.